# IE is still caching page content for a few seconds when META tags are applied. What to do?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, http, caching

I have a scenario where the main website (which I have no control over) is loading my website from within an iframe.  It's a GET with query string parameters chosen by the user on the main website.  The issue is that IE caches my first page inside of that iframe.

I applied the following meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

But IE is still caching it just for about 15 - 20 seconds or so.  So if the user quickly goes back to the main website and chooses something else, they would see the cached version of my first page.  What can I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try busting the cache from the server by setting appropriate HTTP response headers:

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{  
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        cache.SetNoStore();
    }
}
```

and then decorate your controller action that is supposed to serve the `<iframe>` with this attribute:

```
[NoCache]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where does that class go to?  Global.asax?

Comment: @Dimskiy, well, it's an action filter. Usually I stuff them in an `ActionFilters` subfolder but you could really place it whereever you feel comfortable.

Comment: well, what can I say? :) Many thanks for once again resolving my issue!